# Retrieve a particular month SQL Records from Master Table - CDC Enabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table, Table A, in SQL Server that is CDC enabled by Application Programming.

Table A looks like this in Month 1.

```
Policy_ID   DOB      Gender   Occupation CDC_Ind  Load_date        Act_Ind
1           290691    M          ABC       I          01/01/2019     Y
2           290692    M          ABC       I          01/01/2019     Y
3           290693    F          ABC       I          01/01/2019     Y
4           290694    M          ABC       I          01/01/2019     Y
5           290695    F          ABC       I          01/01/2019     Y
```

I receive a new file at the beginning of the next month, Feb 1.

That Feb file looks like this.

```
Policy_ID   DOB      Gender   Occupation 
1           290691    M          ABC  
2           290692    M          ABC   
4           290693    M          ABC 
5           290694    F          DEF     
10          290791    M          ABC
```

It can be seen that `Policy_ID = 3` is not in the new file and `Policy_ID = 10`, a new `ID` is added and `Policy_ID = 4` had a change in Occupation.

So, after running the program this is how Table A changes.

[image]

`CDC_Ind` inferring I for Insert, U for Update and D for Delete and it is done over the Primary Key column `Policy_ID`.

Then the March data comes in

```
Policy_ID   DOB      Gender   Occupation    
11          290791    M          ABC
```

So, now my master table changes to something like this.

[image]

In a real world, I have the data for 50-60 months.

If I want to retrieve a particular month data (leaving `Act_Ind` and `CDC_Ind`) how do I write a query?

**Expected Results for Feb 2019**

```
Policy_ID   DOB      Gender   Occupation 
1           290691    M          ABC  
2           290692    M          ABC   
4           290693    M          ABC 
5           290694    F          DEF     
10          290791    M          ABC
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect for this sample data.

Comment: Can you please show us the expected results for February as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you expect:

```
select Policy_ID, DOB, Gender, Occupation
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by Policy_ID order by Load_date desc) rn
    from masterTable t
    where Load_date < '2019-03-01'
) t
where rn = 1 and CDC_Ind <> 'D'
```

This phrases as: get the last record of each `Policy_ID` prior to the date given as parameter, unless that record has  `CDC_Ind <> 'D'` (ie corresponds to a deletion).

For the date parameter, you want to give the first day of the next month (so for February, you can pass March 1st, as shown in the query).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e6f96e3bc9a793c9010188993bdc563f)**:

```
Policy_ID |    DOB | Gender | Occupation
--------: | -----: | :----- | :---------
        1 | 290691 | M      | ABC       
        2 | 290692 | M      | ABC       
        4 | 290694 | M      | DEF       
        5 | 290695 | F      | ABC       
       10 | 290791 | M      | ABC
```

Comment: That won't work for Feb, if I run it for Feb.Can you please check the expected results.

Comment: @Siddharth: I gave a good second look at your question and I edited my answer. I also added a fiddle, that seems to produce the correct result for your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the most recent record as-of a certain date.

Here is one method:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.load_date = (select max(a2.load_date)
                     from a a2
                     where a2.policy_id = a.policy_id and
                           a2.load_date <= ?   -- date you pass in
                    )
      a.act_ind = 'Y';
```

I would recommend an index on `a(policy_id, load_date)` if your data is largish.

Comment: No, I would like a query where I can pass a particular date and see the data that corresponds to it. I have put down the expected results on the question if I am passing 2/28/2019.

Comment: @Siddharth . . . I fixed the answer.

Comment: No that is not working. I have explained the question more. Can you see if it helps?